# Programmatically authorize a Windows user against a string of users?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, asp.net-mvc-3

Programmatically, I can authorize a Windows user based on whether they are in a particular **role** like this:

```
if(!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    return false;

var isAuthroized = User.IsInRole(@"DOMAIN\Some Role");

// ...

return isAuthorized;
```

What I can't figure out how to do, is how to match a user's name if, for instance, a list of individual users is given access.

So imagine you're trying to authenticate a user against the given string of authorized users, like you would using the normal AuthorizeAttribute:

```
[Authorize(Users = @"DOMAIN\User1, DOMAIN\User2, DOMAIN\User3")]
public ActionResult SomeAction(){ ... }
```

How do you programmatically authorize a user against that string of users?

```
@"DOMAIN\User1, DOMAIN\User2, DOMAIN\User3"
```

**EDIT:** Ok, this is my point of confusion: What is the point of specifying multiple users if you have (in a normal AuthorizeAttribute) a declaration as follows:

```
[Authorize(Users=@"User1,User2,User3", Roles=@"SomeRole"]

// I can do this:

User.IsInRole(roles);

// But what's the equivalent for the specified users?

User.Identity.Name.IsInNames(names); // <-- How is the done programmatically?
```

I'm probably off the mark here, and am missing some piece of information. Please enlighten me!

EDIT 2: The MVC source demystified some of this for me. It is indeed done similar to what was suggested in one of the answers below:

```
if (_usersSplit.Length > 0 &&
   !_usersSplit.Contains(user.Identity.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this *define* a role?

Comment: "authorize a user against a string of users?"? I don't get it.

Comment: Provide your own Role (which will require injecting roles into the User, obviously) that encapsulates the list of users, and a management UI.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a HashSet, as testing the existence of a user is a very fast operation for this collection type.

First, split the string, and then add it to a HashSet.

```
string[] splittedUsers = usersString.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var users = new HashSet<string>(splittedUsers);
```

Test a user like this

```
string user = "xy";
if (users.Contains(user)) {
    // Do something with user
}
```